# Why is the result of this javascript code is an empty array? Thanks

Tags: javascript

Why is the result of this code an empty array?

```js
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

for (let index of arr) {
  arr = arr.filter(value => value == arr[index])
}
console.log(arr) // []
```

Comment: Add a few console.logs to see why

Comment: Without an explanation of what you expect this code to do, it's really impossible to provide useful feedback. The gist is that it does what you programmed it to do: Produce an empty array.

Answer (score 3):

The gist is, you're filtering the array to be empty.

Without knowing what you intend the code to do, we have to assume it's working as intended. But, based on context, there are a bunch of things that *appear* to be wrong here:

First, `index` is not an index, it's the actual element, but you're using it as an index.

This code outputs `1, 2, 3, ...` not, `0, 1, 2, ...`:

```
for (let index of arr) { console.log(index) }
```

Second, each iteration filters out elements that cannot possibly live through the subsequent iteration, so your code as written is designed to produce an empty array.

Finally, you mutate the array as you attempt to iterate over it. `for of` uses an iterator into the original array of 5 elements, it *does* iterate 5 times with the values `1, 2, 3, 4, 5`, but the body of your loop continues to access `arr` as though there are 5 elements in it. That is no true: as you filter elements out of `arr`, `arr[index]` wil longer makes sense. You'll be accessing elements off the end of your array and getting back `undefined`.

---

So, consider your first iteration: You're using the 0th element (`1`) as an index into the array, and `arr[1]` is `2`.

So, you filter the array down to all elements equal to `2`, which is `2`. So, after the first iteration, your array `arr` is replaced with `[2]`.

Your second iteration, index is `2`, but you've overwritten `arr` with `[2]`. It no longer has an element at `arr[2]`, so you attempt to further filter the array down to all elements that are equal to `undefined`. There *are no elements equal to `undefined`*, so the new array is `[]`.

Each subsequent iteration is given an empty array. `filter` can only remove elements, so the array will be empty from that point forwards.

Answer (score 0):

index here `let index of arr` is 1,2,3.. but it does not start from zero.
In the first iteration `arr` is `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`. Also in first iteration `index` is 1, so `arr[index]` is same as `arr[1]` which is 2. So during first iteration filter will return only [2].

From next iteration onward no value will be matched. So filter will return an empty array

```js
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

for (let index of arr) {
  console.log(arr)
  arr = arr.filter((value) => {
    console.log(index, value)
    return value == arr[index]
  })
}
console.log(arr)
```